# solenoid kick back

Tags: coil, physics

This may be a bit of a physics question but when you fire a solenoid with the rod, does it have any backward force? Newton's third law states for every action, there is an equal and opposite reaction, is this the same for the solenoid?

Comment: yes of course...

Comment: It is a physics question.  Off topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really a physics question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electronic and electro-mechanical components do not defy the laws of physics. Of course there is some "kick back" when a solenoid fires, though depending on what you're trying to do and what type of solenoid you have, this force is likely very small relative to the size and weight of the solenoid. I can only imagine you're trying to come up with some sort of propulsion or perpetual motion device, and to that I say that the force applied when you fire the solenoid probably won't get you much in the way of movement.